# Kann ein Relativsatz das Verb in zweiter Position haben?

Tags: verb, word-order, relative-clause

Beim Lesen eines Märchens der Gebrüder Grimm habe ich den folgenden Satz gelesen:

Es war einmal ein König, ***der hatte eine Tochter***.

Meine Frage ist, soll der Relativsatz nicht ***der eine Tochter hatte*** sein?

Warum ist das Verb nicht am Ende des Satzes? Ist es kein Relativsatz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich behaupte mal frech, da ist gar kein Relativsatz. Man kann das Komma ohne Sinnverlust durch einen Punkt ersetzen und hat zwei Hauptsätze.

> Es war einmal ein König. Der hatte eine Tochter.

oder - bekanntes Kinder-Nonsense-Gedicht:

> Es war einmal ein Mann. Der hatte einen Schwamm.

*Der* im jeweils zweiten Satz ist damit kein Relativ- sondern ein Demonstrativpronomen.

Latein kennt eine ähnliche Form und nennt sie *relativer Anschluß*.

Comment: Dieses Konstrukt nennt sich übrigens Hauptsatzreihe. (Und das mit dem relativen Anschluss ist meiner Meinung nach weit hergeholt. „der“ kann einfach ein Demonstrativpronomen sein, ganz egal wo es im Satz steht. Ich kann ja auch „Einen Schwamm hatte der.“ sagen.)

Answer (score 4):

Ich betrachte das nicht als einen Relativsatz. "Der" ist hier als "er" zu verstehen. Ich sehe das Ganze als Zwei Sätze (nur mit Komma statt Punkt):

> Es war einmal ein König, der (er, jener König) hatte eine Tochter.

Answer (score 3):

Dies ist *eine Formel* für Märchenanfänge, daher eher stilistisch als grammatisch bedingt. Ich würde sagen, es ist ein Relativsatz mit einer Wortfolge, die als Kunstgriff aufgefasst werden kann. Wenn ein Bericht so anfängt, weiss man sofort, dass es ein Märchen ist.